# Ошибка при обновлении ядра Drupal

Tags: php, база-данных, drupal

Обновил ядро друпал с версии 7.64, на версию 8.6.13, после обновления не открывается сайт, а появляется следующее:

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again
>   later.Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException:
>   in Drupal\Core\PathProcessor\PathProcessorFront->processInbound()
>   (line 43 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/PathProcessor/PathProcessorFront.php).

При попытке команды /update.php появляется следующее:

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
>   Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException:
>   You have requested a non-existent service "access_check.db_update". in
>   Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->getDefinition()
>   (line 1053 of
>   vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/ContainerBuilder.php).

Как исправить данную ошибку, без использования сохранённой копии сайта?

Answer (score 1):

Никак. У D7 и D8 разные архитектуры. Вам нужно установить D8 c нуля отдельно.
Затем либо с помощью браузера по пути ваш_сайт/upgrade,
либо выборочно [с помощью drush](https://www.powercms.in/blog/drupal-how-migrate-content-types-taxonomy-term-and-users-drupal-7-drupal-8-using-drush) попробовать [произвести миграцию](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/upgrade/upgrading-from-drupal-6-or-7-to-drupal-8).
Затем Вам придётся пересобрать сайт: тему, кастом-код шаблонов и кастом-модуля (если есть).